# Block async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a class `Reader` that creates `Task` and reads data in batches. Each time it finishes reading a batch it reports progress via `IProgress` passed in parameter. Then I save the batch to NoSQL database. The problem is it sometimes can report progress faster than saving batch to database.

I think that a good solution would be to block `Task` if saving hasn't finished yet. I don't really know how to implement that. I need something that will notify that reading has finished and then wait for notification that saving to db has finished and it can continue reading.

pseudo-code:

**Reader:**

```
public async Task<bool> ReadAsync(IProgress<Tuple<DataTable, int>> statusCallback) {
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while(lineCount <= BufferSize) {
         // Read data
        }
    statusCallback.Report(new Tuple<DataTable, int>(data, progress);
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
public Main() {
    var progress = new Progress<Tuple<DataTable, int>>(ReaderStatusCallback);
    reader.ReadAsync(progress);
}

private void ReaderStatusCallback(Tuple<DataTable, int> tuple)
{
    var data = tuple.Item1.ToDocumentData();
    var progress = tuple.Item2;

    _progressBar.Increment(progress);
    _docData.Data = data;
    _repository.Add(_docData);
}
```

Comment: Is your saving task async too?

Comment: No, I save it on UI thread

Comment: It would be easier to come up with ideas if you have had posted some pseudo code. I am assuming the reader class is using a loop. Perhaps you could have a singleton class for saving and have a flag for it that shows if it is busy or not and in your reader loop, check that flag before trying to read a new batch. Your can get fancy and use events to inform the reader class when the save is done, or just use a loop, constantly checking the value of the flag, until it is ready. Waiting (or blocking) the async method, is somewhat against the idea of async programming though

Comment: I added pseudo-code. Thank you for your idea, but I would prefer to do it with some kind of blocking rather than flags and repeated value checking

Comment: `The problem is it sometimes can report progress faster than saving batch to database.` I don't see how this is a problem. Can you expound on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to not use an implementation of `IProgress<T>` that dispatches updates asynchronously. For example:

```
class BasicProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> _handler;

    public BasicProgress(Action<T> handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    private void IProgress<T>.Report(T value)
    {
        _handler(value);
    }
}
```

Then the call to `statusCallback.Report()` won't return until the database has been updated.

Without more context, it's impossible to say for sure what's actually best. But you might find some value in allowing the database updates to queue up at least to some degree. In which case, you can modify the idea above by still using the synchronous `IProgress<T>` implementation, but dispatching the update asynchronously in your `ReaderStatusCallback()` method, and adding a counter to keep track of how many of those are currently outstanding, and waiting in the callback if that counter exceeds some reasonable threshold.

Now, all that said…it seems likely that you are running into this issue because you are reading from some source that is significantly faster than the database itself is. If that's the case, it's questionable why any of this should be done asynchronously at all. Maybe there's something you're not sharing that justifies the asynchronous approach, but based on what you've posted so far, it seems that the entire reading-and-updating-database logic should just be in a single thread/worker/task/whatever.